# Why do I get an error when running npm run dev?

Tags: npm, next.js

I ran `npm run dev` and expected it to open my next.js on localhost but am getting this error.

```
PS C:\Users\mebck\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\next> npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> next@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink 'C:\Users\mebck\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\next\.next\server\middleware-manifest.json'] {
  type: 'Error',
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'readlink',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\mebck\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Proyectos\\next\\.next\\server\\middleware-manifest.json'
}
```